# How do i simplify these two similar like queries?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have these two queries in a method in controller:

```
    $tools=Tool::where('tool_date','>',$now)->orderBy('tool_date')->get()->take(3);

    $keys=Tool::select('name as title','tool_date as start')->get()->toJson();

    return view('index')->with(['tools'=>$tools,'keys'=>$keys,'now'=>$now]);
```

The first is used in blade as:

```
@foreach($tools as $tool)
{{$tool->name}}
...
@endforeach
```

Whereas, the second is used in javascript as:

```
<script>
    eventSources: [
                {
                    events:
                            {!! $keys !!},

                        color: 'black',     
                        textColor: 'red' 
                }
           ]
</script>
```

How can i simplify these two queries and combine into one?

Comment: The two queries are not similar and hold two different set of data. For convenience sake you could create a single collection or array to hold both the data and pass it to the view and use it accordingly. There's no real benefit to doing that. Also you need to use `take(3)` before `get()`, if not you're fetching all results from the db and then taking 3 items from d result collection.

Comment: @Sandeesh i need a collection in second one but only take 3 of those for the first. so, i am only indicating there is this take(3) also, if there is any simplifed version.

Comment: When you do `->get()->take(3);` the query generated will fetch all the rows matching your condition and after the fetch laravel will take 3 rows on the result. This is an unwanted waste of resource. So you do `->take(3)->get();` , which fetches only 3 rows directly from the database.

Comment: @Sandeesh Yes. but, anyway i require all rows from the database for the second one. and take 3 from same collection for the first one.

Comment: alright i think i have an idea to optimize this with a single query, gimme a minute

Comment: I've added my answer. It's the ideal optimization with a single query which produces both the data you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php:

```
$tools=Tool::select('name as title','tool_date as start')->where('tool_date','>',$now)->orderBy('tool_date')->get();

return view('index')->with(['tools'=>$tools]);
```

first use in blade:

```
@foreach($tools->take(3) as $tool
{{$tool->title}}
...
@endforeach
```

second use:

```
<script>
eventSources: [
            {
                events:
                        {!! $tools->toJson() !!},

                    color: 'black',     
                    textColor: 'red' 
            }
       ]
```

Thats one query, and manage of collections.

Comment: i need to skip this in second one: `->where('tool_date','>',$now)` and add `$tools->where('tool_date','>',$now)->take(3)` instead. then, is this simplied again?

Comment: try: `$tools->take(3)->toJson()`

Answer (score 1):

The prefared way is:

```
$tools = Tool::whereDate('tool_date','>',$now)->orderBy('tool_date')->take(3)->get();
```

**combine** As **usual**:

```
$keys = Tool::select('name as title','tool_date as start')->whereDate('start','>',$now)->orderBy('start')->take(3)->get();
```

**But** in your situation, you can't combine as it looks you want to deal with different data for **view** and **script**.

**also,** try the combine and make the following changes and see if that's you want:

```
@foreach($keys as $key)
{{$key->name}}
...
@endforeach


<script>
eventSources: [
  {
    events:
      {!! $keys->toJson !!},
      color: 'black',     
      textColor: 'red' 
  }
];
</script>
```

Comment: i need to skip this in second one: `->whereDate('tool_date','>',$now)` and add `$keys->where('tool_date','>',$now)->take(3)` instead. then, is this simplied again?

Answer (score 1):

Ok this gives you the exact same result as your existing queries and does so with a single database fetch.

```
$allTools = Tool::all();

$tools = $allTools->filter(function ($tool) use ($now) {
    return \Carbon\Carbon::parse($tool->tool_date)->gt(\Carbon\Carbon::parse($now));
})->sortBy('tool_date')->take(3);

$keys = $allTools->transform(function ($tool) {
    return [
        'title' => $tool->name,
        'start' => $tool->tool_date
    ];
})->toJson();
```

In your question you fetch every tool for your keys, but you've accepted an answer which gives you the keys of tools that only match your first condition.

Comment: Wasted effort if that was your expected result. Next time you could be clearer in your question about the expected result so that people like us who help you don't waste our time. Good day.

Comment: I appreciate your effort and it is not wasted. I've observed it too.